# Data type of array with more than 4 dimension?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, methods, properties

I have to comment a parameter of a class but i don't know the datatype

This is what i the comment that i used, is it correct?

```
class Annunci{

    /** @var mixed[] */
    public $dataDecode;
    
}
```

This the value of $dataDecode.

```
Array
(
    [listing] => Array
    (
        [id] => 96888022
        [type] => ad
        [isProjectLike] =>
        [contract] => Array
            (
                [type] => rent
                [name] => Affitto
                [value] => Affitto, 4+4
            )

        [advertiser] => Array
            (
                [agency] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 384428
                        [uuid] => 228f7e3f-4cb3-51c0-912c-72a9336d6b9d
                        [type] => agency
                        [customType] =>
                        [label] => agenzia
                        [displayName] => Dils Living
                        [imageUrls] => Array
                            (
                                [small] => https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/1140131182.jpg
                                [large] => https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/1140131184.jpg
                            ) 
)
```

Comment: /** @var array */